# Override an url with hook_menu_alter : problem with the file path

Tags: 6, routes

In 'mymodule', i try to override a menu url with hook_menu_alter, like this :

```
global $base_url;

$items['node/%node/delete'] = array(
  'page arguments' => array('myfunction', 1),
  'file' => $base_url .'/'. drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') .'/includes/custom_node_delete_confirm.inc',
);
```

I have an error because the file path is relative and begins with a "/"

```
Failed opening required
'/http://localhost/mysite/sites/all/modules/mymodule/includes/custom_node_delete_confirm.inc'
```

and this doesn't work too:

```
'file' => 'includes/custom_node_delete_confirm.inc'
```

How can i do this ? Thank You

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the `file path` explicitly:

> **file path:** The path to the directory containing the file specified in "file". This defaults to the path to the module implementing the hook.

So your code might look like:

```
$items['node/%node/delete']['page arguments'] = array('myfunction', 1);
$items['node/%node/delete']['file'] = 'includes/custom_node_delete_confirm.inc';
$items['node/%node/delete']['file path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');
```

Be careful not to completely overwrite an existing router item unless you absolutely need to, in your example you're removing the required `access callback`/`access arguments`, and also the title; instead only change the values you need to as in the example above.

Comment: It works, and you are right, i just need to override "page arguments" and "file". Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
'file' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/includes/custom_node_delete_confirm.inc',
```

Comment: doesn't work :Failed opening required 'modules/node/sites/all/modules/mymodule/includes/custom_node_delete_confirm.inc

Comment: because the module implementing the hook is the node module

Comment: This does not work because the file attribute already uses the full path to the original module location, like that: `Warning: require_once(/var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/old_module/sites/all/modules/new_module/new_module.pages.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.